# Creating Function Sheet in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to automate a function that has already been created in one of my Excel workbooks as such:

[image: Desired Process]

Although this example is just calculating the mean, median and mode or a data set, what my real function is doing is much more complicated. This function is basically a series of cell formulas that do a bunch of math on that sheet and then give out a few outputs based on inputs.

Instead of writing a formula in directly, you're calling a function which contains the cells of a bunch of formulas that make up the function. The way I most easily can compare this to would be like a function file in Matlab where you give the function inputs when calling the function and then getting outputs.

But in this case the sheet outputs a bunch of cells that I just want to get reference values for. Sorry if this isn't clear. If need be I can try to provide an example function.

[image: Just the def of a function...]

The only method I can find online that would work would be creating a new function formula using developer modules which seems like a pain and so I'm hoping there's a simpler way.

Comment: @BlindSpots I edited the first picture to try to make it more clear. Basically data on one sheet, formulas on another, want post processed data on third. I'll look into that function. If that's still not clear enough, I'll write up a simple example

Comment: @BlindSpots not necessarily without formulas, just being able to see what the results are for all series. I updated the first photo with an example

Comment: Is the middle table calculation process of the output?